# What's the difference between CMP and CMN?

Tags: assembly, arm

The lecture slides says that CMN performs a comparison by 'adding' the 2's complement of the 2nd operand to the first operand, and CMP performs comparison by 'subtracting' the 2nd operand from the first operand. But by what I've learned so far, arm instructions within the processor performs additions only and subtraction is achieved by doing a 2's complement of the second operand(please, tell me if this is correct or not). So isn't CMN and CMP basically doing the same thing???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like your lecture slides are slightly mixed up. The point of CMP is that if the two operands are equal then the result is zero, which means `cmp a, b` is simply `a - b`. CMN makes the same comparison but with the second operand negated, i.,e. `cmn a, b` means `a - (-b)` - which under two's complement arithmetic is exactly equivalent to `a + b`.

Comment: Ah, so CMN also does a subtraction to compare the two operands except the second operand is negated to an opposite sign. Is that correct?

Comment: Indeed. It probably starts making more sense when you consider that you can't directly encode negative immediates in the operand2 format.